# How do you write multiline if/else statements with inline javascript HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm basically trying to produce jQuery effects based on the data I am coming in with from the server.  I've tried multiple methods but its not coming out correctly

```
:javascript
  "#{if @user.nil?}"
    $('#test-container').show();
  "#{end}"
```

Comment: This has been discussed elsewhere: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/210943 The conclusion seems to be that what you are trying to do is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree - I tend to put needed data in tag attributes in some appropriate place on the page and then pick them up with the script. In that way the scripts stay clear of backend dependencies (other than the markup!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `#{...}` need to be a single expression, and is allowed to go over multiple lines. Inside `#{...}` you can use literal strings simply by quoting them, and you don’t need quotes around the whole thing.

```haml
:javascript
  #{if @user.nil?
  "$('#test-container').show();"
  end}
```

In this case you can do it as a single line:

```haml
:javascript
  #{"$('#test-container').show();" if @user.nil?}
```

In general you want to avoid complex multiline interpolated blocks like in the first example. If necessary you should look at creating helpers to keep your views simple and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
- unless @user
  :javascript
    $('#test-container').show();
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.  It treats it as javascript code.  They only way I've been able to use ruby code is to use "#{@user}"

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.  I want to be able to do this in the javascript code, and not create entire javascript blocks based on the server values. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem. If you code is more than what you showed though, then I would put it in a separate file, something like your_action.js.haml. Another alternative would be to use Erb for this.